# Xcode show current file classes and methods in always visible panel

Tags: xcode

In one source file i have different classes... i want the class and methods drop down always be visible, so navigation is easier

Is there a way to accomplish this? plugin?

[image]

Comment: The symbol navigator? The minimap?

Comment: minimap is useless... symbol navigator shows for the whole project and not auto for the current file, also when switched to symbol navigator, i cannot use the file navigator

Comment: @PeterLapisu I'd love to have the same feature since Xcode 3.0 but unfortunately I haven't found solution yet